# Lightning experience embedded page redirect

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, lightning-experience, pagereference, redirect

I've got a VF page embedded into page layout. It redirects user to other VF pages (depending on user action) inside an iframe on page layout.

In LE such PageReference redirects sort 'step out' from the layout -- they are still shown in LE but not in the detail page.

JS redirects via `sforce.one` work the same way for me. Has anyone managed to build embedded page redirects with that? What strategy would work for that? Will I have to turn my app into a single-page-app?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's by design. You'll probably need to pass a return URL around to get back to the original place you came from when you're done. Are you intending to show the entire process within the single area of the page layout?

Comment: hi @sfdcfox, yes, I want to show all pages at the same area on a record detail page (as it now works with several VF pages and PageReference redirects between them via Apex controllers)